# Email attachment Fatal Error

Tags: php, email, attachment

I'm trying to get my php to send an email which works fine now but im now attempting it to work with an attachment with it which is already on the server so there is no upload involved. But when I run it I get this fatal error: 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function addattachment() in /home3/hutch/public_html/Murphy/EmailerTest.php on line 19` So i'm assuming i'm writing the `addAttachemnt($path);` or `$path` incorrectly. Could someone clear this up for me?

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");

$path = "<IMAGES/Logo.jpg>"; 

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.sulmaxmarketing.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "info@sulmaxmarketing.com";
$mail->FromName = "Murphy's Online Documentation System";
$mail->AddAddress("sulmaxcp@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = "Senior Managers Site Tour";
$mail->Body     = "You've just recieved an document via the Murphy's Senior Managers Site Tour website.\n Your document is in the attachments";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
AddAttachment($path);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "<font color='#009900' align=centre> ERROR: Something has gone wrong, please contact the site administrator.</font>";
} 

else {
echo "<font color='#CC0033' align=centre>SUCCESS: You're Senior Managers Site Tour document has been sent.</font>";
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP is telling you that function doesn't exist. Where is AddAttachment defined? You need to write that function and make it do something. Should it be `$mail->AddAttachment()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay all fixed forgot to add `$mail->` to `AddAttachment($path);` then lastly sorted out the location of the `$path` and it all works a dream now.